# Post form results into COLORBOX modal

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I have a page with file upload form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploaded.php">
   <input type="file" name="my_file">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I need to post results into a modal window created with colorbox jQuery plugin.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Does anyone know how do do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Colorbox is client-side, upload server-side. You have to create a php page which displays uploaded images and "apply" colorbox on it.