# colorbox post form values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using colorbox to create an email submit dialog that will be pre-populated with data mostly generated on the server side but I also require some data from input boxes on the client side (parent/calling page).

My problem is that jquery doesn't seem to be working in the data object. authorisation_number, in the example below, don't seem to be getting resolved to the value that is in that field. When I check the POST data on the server `authorisation_number` is empty despite their being text in that input field when I click the button to launch the modal.

```
    // MODAL: Email Someone
    $("#email_person").colorbox({

                width: "760",
                height: "800",
                data: {
                    template             : 'email-person-auth',
                    callref              : 12345,
                    email_add            : 'test@test.com',
                    authorisation_number : $('#authorisation_number').val()
                }
    });
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' name='authorisation_number' id='authorisation_number'>
<input type='button' class='submit_button' id='email_person' value='Email Someone' href='{{ url("customer-services/send-email") }}' >
```

Does anyone know how to add data from the parent page to be posted?

Comment: you could see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918606/post-form-results-into-colorbox-modal?rq=1

Comment: thanks, but I'd already read that. It does not answer the question on how you post variable data from the parent page, e.g. values entered by users into input fields.

Comment: An update on this. If the field is given a value on page load it seems to post that so it looks like jquery works within the data object but I need to get it to check the latest value <input type='text' name='authorisation_number' id='authorisation_number' value='1234'>

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around the solution seems to be that you take the modal instantiation outside of the document ready function

```
function emailPerson() {

           $("#email_person").colorbox({

                width: "760",
                height: "800",
                data: {
                    template             : 'email-person-auth',
                    callref              : 12345,
                    email_add            : 'test@test.com',
                    authorisation_number : $('#authorisation_number').val()
                }
          });
}
```

and then you can use

```
$("#email_person").click(function() {
    emailPerson();
});
```

Hope this solution helps others.